# Segmentation fault on separate chaining hashtable

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, hashtable

So i implemented a hashtable with separate chaining for a struct called Objective, so that i could perform some operations on said Objectives. Currently i have this:

Hashtable.h:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Using separate chaining to store the obejctives*/

typedef struct Objective{
char name [8000];
unsigned long id, duration, deps [9000];
int hasDeps;
}*pObjective;

typedef struct nodehash{       /*Node of list*/
   pObjective obj;
   struct nodehash*next;
}*link;


void Init(int M);
int search(unsigned long id);
void insert(pObjective o);
void delete(unsigned long id);
link insertBegin(link h, pObjective obj);
int searchList(link h, unsigned long id);
link removeList(link h, unsigned long id);
pObjective searchObj(unsigned long id);
pObjective searchObjAux(link h, unsigned long id);



#endif
```

Objectives.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "OBJECTIVES.h"

/*Checks if all inserted dependencies already exist*/

int existDeps(unsigned long dep[9000]){
    int i, count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 9000; i++){
      if(search(dep[i]) != 0)
        count++;
    }
     return count;
}

/ *Adds objective with dependencies*/

void addObj(unsigned long id, char name [8000], unsigned long duration,
    unsigned long dep[9000]){
      int i;

    pObjective obj = malloc(sizeof(pObjective));
    obj->id = id;
    obj->duration = duration;
    obj->hasDeps = 1;
    strcpy(name, obj->name);

    for(i = 0; i < 9000; i++){
       obj->deps[i] = dep[i];
    }
    if(search(id) != 0)
       printf("id already exists\n");
   else if(existDeps(dep) != 0)
       printf("no such task\n");
   else
       insert(obj);

   free(obj);

   }

   /*Adds objective with no dependencies*/

   void addNoDeps(unsigned long id, char name [8000], unsigned long 
       duration){

   pObjective obj = malloc(sizeof(pObjective));
   obj->id = id;
   obj->duration = duration;
   obj->hasDeps = 1;
   strcpy(name, obj->name);

   if(search(id) != 0)
      printf("id already exists\n");
   else
     insert(obj);

   free(obj);

   }

  /*Removes objective with no dependencies*/

  void removeObj(unsigned long id){
        int res = search(id);
        pObjective obj = searchObj(id);

      if(res == 0)
         printf("no such task\n");
      else if(obj->hasDeps == 1)
         printf("task with dependencies\n");
      else
      delete(id);


      }
```

Objectives.h:

```
     #ifndef OBJECTIVES_H
     #define OBJECTIVES_H
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include "HASHTABLE.h"

     /*Functions to work with objectives*/

    int existDeps(unsigned long dep[9000]);
    void addObj(unsigned long id, char name [8000], unsigned long duration,
    unsigned long dep[9000]);
    void addNoDeps(unsigned long id, char name [8000], unsigned long 
    duration);
    void removeObj(unsigned long id);    

    #endif
```

Hashtable.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HASHTABLE.h"

#define hash(A,B) (A%B)  /*Hash function*/

static link *heads;
static int M;

 /*Initiates hashtable with size m*/

 void Init(int m){
  int i;
  M = m;
  heads = (link*)malloc(M*sizeof(link));
  for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    heads[i] = NULL;
  }

/*Searches objective with said id*/

int search(unsigned long id){
   int i = hash(id, M);
   return searchList(heads[i], id);
}

/*Inserts objective into hashtable*/

   void insert(pObjective o){
   int i = hash(o->id, M);
   heads[i] = insertBegin(heads[i], o);
   }

 /*Deletes objective using it's id*/

 void delete(unsigned long id){
   int i = hash(id, M);
   heads[i] = removeList(heads[i], id);
  }

   /*Returns objective with said id*/

   pObjective searchObj(unsigned long id){
    int i = hash(id, M);
    return searchObjAux(heads[i], id);
   }

   /*Inserts objective into list*/

   link insertBegin(link h, pObjective obj){

   link new = (link)malloc(sizeof(struct nodehash));
   new->obj = obj;
   new->next = h;
   return new;

   }

   /*Searches objective by id in a list*/

   int searchList(link h, unsigned long id){
     link t;
     int count = 0;
     for(t = h; t != NULL; t = t->next){
        if(t->obj->id == id)
          count++;
   }
   return count++;

   }

   /*Removes objective from list*/

   link removeList(link h, unsigned long id){
      link t, x, z;
      for(t = h; t != NULL; t = t->next){
         if(t->next->obj->id == id)
            x = t;
      }
      z = x->next;
      x->next = z->next;
      free(z);
      return h;
  }

  /*Returns objetive from said id from list*/

  pObjective searchObjAux(link h, unsigned long id){
     link t, x;
     for(t = h; t != NULL; t = t->next){
       if(t->obj->id == id)
         x = t;
     }
     return x->obj;
  }
```

I'm quick testing the funcions addObj (adds an objective with dependencies) and addNoDeps (adds an objective with no dependencies) on my main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "OBJECTIVES.h"


int main(){
  unsigned long array [1] = {3};
  Init(11);
  addNoDeps(1, "tarefa1", 20);
  addObj(2, "tarefa2", 20, array);
  return 0;
}
```

But i keep getting segmentation fault(core dumped) and i can't figure out why. Is my implementation wrong? Are the functions wrong? I can't get to the problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't run your code right now so I can't analyze the core dump, but I believe what is happening is that you are trying to access memory that has already been freed. At the end of addNoDeps, you free the pObjective after putting it into the list. Then, when you addObj after, you search the list and check to make sure that the links object associated with it is not null. Specifically this code:

```
    for(t = h; t != NULL; t = t->next){
    if(t->obj->id == id)
      count++;
```

You only check to see that the t (links pointer) is not null, but since you freed the previous object, the t->obj pointer is not pointing to initialized memroy. Therefore trying to access it via t->obj->id is accessing uninitialized memory. If you remove the `free(obj)` at the end of your addNoDeps and addObj functions you should be fine. You may also want to add checks to make sure that t->obj is not null as well. In general segmentation faults are caused by accessing uninitialized memory, so when debugging check for accessing pointers after a free, double frees, and other things. Also learning to use GDB can help a lot in these situations.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice,I removed the free(obj) and added checks to see if t->obj is not NULL but i still get segmentation fault...

Comment: I used GDB and basically the addObj, addNoDeps and all the functions where i iterate through the list (searchList, removeList, searchObjAux) keep giving seg fault... is it something wrong with my implementation of the hashtable?

Comment: Okay so the other things you need to do are a. in the `strcpy(name, obj->name)` in both addObj and addDepObj just switch name and obj->name. strcpy is `strcpy(destination, source)` . The other thing is you are giving addObj an array of size 1 but the parameter expects an array of size 9000? I'm not sure what you want but you'll get another segfault there if you try and access past what you give. You should probably pass an array size as well so the function doesn't go past. After I fixed those things your code built and ran fine on my machine.

Comment: I never know the size of the array i want to add, only that its max number of elements is 9000, thats why, when I declared the struct, i declared deps as an array with 9000 elemens, but it can have between 0 and 9000 elements. In the method AddObj the paramether dep can have in between 1 and 9000 elements. Should i change the struct element deps and the dep in AddObj to a pointer? Because when i declare an array size as 9000 i can never change it back.

Comment: Changing dep to a pointer changes nothing about the problem. If you don't know the size of the array you want to add you will never be able to iterate over it, because you will never know how far to iterate. Find some way to keep track of the size.